# Nested form to invoke custom factory method instead of new()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This problem is related to this question: [Hashing an IP for saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005081/hashing-an-ip-for-saving-should-this-go-to-the-controller-or-model)

I have a model called Post. I have to pass in the IP address during post creation. I was told not to override the initialize(). So I used a factory method as suggested here: [how to override new method for a rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376992/how-to-override-new-method-for-a-rails-model):

```
#Post.rb model
def self.new_with_ip(ip, attributes={})
  self.new(attributes['one_day_id'] = do_some_conversion_on(ip))
end
```

However this does not get invoked, because Post is nested within a Discussion, and the nested form will not call this factory method. How can I make the form to invoke this instead of the traditional `Post.new()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is being passed through as a nested attribute of a form then you would have to override the `posts_attributes=` method of the `Discussion` model:

```
def posts_attributes=(attribute_sets)
  attribute_sets.each do |attributes|
    Post.new_with_ip(ip_goes_here, attributes)
  end
end
```

Of course you're going to need to modify that a little if you're going to be getting nested posts in an update kind of fashion, as you'll want to update existing posts rather than creating new ones. Sounds like a good exercise in learning :)

Comment: thanks. Does it mean that I have to add a factory method to the Discussion in order to pass IP address from the controller?

Comment: @lulalala: You could set `ip` as a virtual attribute (using `attr_accessor`) on your `Discussion` model and set it as you pass through the parameters from the controller.